# Animation nodes: custom falloff shape?

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there a way to make your own custom falloff in animation nodes besides the default sphere or directional falloff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use `Custom Falloff` node to make your own falloffs. For example we can make Mesh falloff using `BVH Tree` and `Custom Falloff` node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use multiple effectors? also when i rotate it using "compose matrix" with a "object transforms input" my effector becomes distorted and out of place